# Error in enabling json support in php on centos

Tags: gcc, centos, yum

I'm trying to enable JSON support in PHP on a CentOS server. But after running

'# yum install gcc" or any other package I'm given this error:

" Fatal Python error: PyString_InternInPlace: strings only please! Aborted"

How can I resolve it?

Comment: This is probably a "Server Fault" question, as it seems to me the problem is in your CentOS box - probably broken python packages. Check this thread to see what packages are broken: http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=17872&forum=37

Comment: I'd say this is more Power Users, because if you were a Sysadmin, OP would have looked into these places first ;)